# Built MS Project from Excel skipping empty rows

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

This question is not that much about any application but more about finding algorithm that would work.
I have a code for moving data from Excel to MS Project. My current solution works until I don't have empty rows in between.

I have data starting from row 19. So 19 - 18 is first task, 20 - 18 is second task and so on. However once I have empty rows in between, let's say:

```
Task 1 (row 19)
Task 2 (row 20)

Task 3 (row 22)
```

My code is not working as there is task 2 in MS Project and next should be number 3, however 22 - 18 is 4. Anybody have any good solution for this?

Here is the code:

```
    ' Move data to project
    For i = 19 To lRow
    
        strValue = WorksheetToOperate.Range("C" & i)
        strStartDate = WorksheetToOperate.Range("E" & i)
        strEndDate = WorksheetToOperate.Range("F" & i)
        Strresource = WorksheetToOperate.Range("J" & i)
        
        ' Import tasks
        If (WorksheetToOperate.Range("C" & i).Value <> "") And _
        (Not IsError(WorksheetToOperate.Range("C" & i).Value)) Then
            newproj.Tasks.Add strValue
        End If
        
        ' Import start date
        If (WorksheetToOperate.Range("E" & i).Value <> "") And _
        (Not IsError(WorksheetToOperate.Range("E" & i).Value)) Then
            newproj.Tasks(i - 18).Start = strStartDate
        End If
        
        ' Import end date
        If (WorksheetToOperate.Range("F" & i).Value <> "") And _
        (Not IsError(WorksheetToOperate.Range("F" & i).Value)) Then
            newproj.Tasks(i - 18).Finish = strEndDate
        End If
        
        ' Import recources
        If Not ExistsInCollection(newproj.Resources, Strresource) Then _
        newproj.Resources.Add.Name = Strresource
        
        If (WorksheetToOperate.Range("J" & i).Value <> "") And _
        (Not IsError(WorksheetToOperate.Range("J" & i).Value)) Then
            newproj.Tasks(i - 18).ResourceNames = Strresource
        End If
    
    Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of skipping empty rows is greatly simplified by using a [Task object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.tasks(object)) variable to keep track of the task that was just added. Also, use the `With` statement with the Worksheet object to further simplify the code.

```
Sub CreateSchedule()

    Dim prj As MSProject.Application
    Set prj = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
    prj.Visible = True
    
    Dim newProj As MSProject.Project
    Set newProj = prj.Projects.Add
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim t As MSProject.Task
    
    For i = 19 To 28 'lRow
        With WorksheetToOperate
            If Not IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i)) Then
                Set t = newProj.Tasks.Add(CStr(.Range("C" & i)))
                t.Start = CDate(.Range("E" & i))
                t.Finish = CDate(Range("F" & i))
                t.ResourceNames = CStr(.Range("J" & i))
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it working with additional variable `m`:

```
    Dim m
    m = 0

    ' Move data to project
    For i = 19 To lRow
        
        If IsEmpty(WorksheetToOperate.Range("C" & i).Value) Then
        
            m = m + 1
        
        Else
        
            strValue = WorksheetToOperate.Range("C" & i)
            strStartDate = WorksheetToOperate.Range("E" & i)
            strEndDate = WorksheetToOperate.Range("F" & i)
            Strresource = WorksheetToOperate.Range("J" & i)
        
            ' Import tasks
            If (WorksheetToOperate.Range("C" & i).Value <> "") And _
            (Not IsError(WorksheetToOperate.Range("C" & i).Value)) Then
                newproj.Tasks.Add strValue
            End If
            
            ' Import start date
            If (WorksheetToOperate.Range("E" & i).Value <> "") And _
            (Not IsError(WorksheetToOperate.Range("E" & i).Value)) Then
                newproj.Tasks(i - (18 + m)).Start = strStartDate
            End If
            
            ' Import end date
            If (WorksheetToOperate.Range("F" & i).Value <> "") And _
            (Not IsError(WorksheetToOperate.Range("F" & i).Value)) Then
                newproj.Tasks(i - (18 + m)).Finish = strEndDate
            End If
            
            ' Import recources
            If Not ExistsInCollection(newproj.Resources, Strresource) Then _
            newproj.Resources.Add.Name = Strresource
            
            If (WorksheetToOperate.Range("J" & i).Value <> "") And _
            (Not IsError(WorksheetToOperate.Range("J" & i).Value)) Then
                newproj.Tasks(i - (18 + m)).ResourceNames = Strresource
            End If
            
        End If
    
    Next i
```